# How does bidirectional encoding allow the predicted word to indirectly "see itself"?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, recurrent-neural-networks, bert

Before the release of BERT, we used to say that it is not possible to train bidirectional models by simply conditioning each word on its previous and next words, since this would allow the word that's being predicted to indirectly "see itself" in a multi-layer model. How does this happen?

Comment: Check out my answer on Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/446049/24612